# Natural transformation as an argument in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a way to define natural transformation as a simple argument to pass to a function.

Let's have a simple function as an example:

```
mapK :: (m Int -> IO Int) -> Kleisli m Bool Int -> Kleisli IO Bool Int
mapK toIO kleisli = Kleisli (\bool -> toIO $ runKleisli kleisli bool)
```

Neat, but if I change it to:

```
mapK :: (m a -> IO a) -> Kleisli m Bool Int -> Kleisli IO Bool Int
mapK toIO kleisli = Kleisli (\bool -> toIO $ runKleisli kleisli bool)
```

I get the error that `Int` isn't an `a` (no surprise there).

I know it's possible to achieve it using constraint like:

```
class NaturalTransformation f g where
  transform :: f a -> g a

mapK :: (NaturalTransformation m IO) => Kleisli m Bool Int -> Kleisli IO Bool Int
```

but I'm curious if it's also possible to do it in plain arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainly, you just need to demand that the implementer, not the caller, gets to choose the variable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
mapK :: (forall a. m a -> IO a) -> Kleisli m Bool Int -> Kleisli IO Bool Int
-- implementation is exactly as before
mapK toIO kleisli = Kleisli (toIO . runKleisli kleisli)
-- OR, with TypeApplications also on,
mapK toIO = coerce @(_ (Bool -> _ Int)) (toIO.)
```

Comment: Ah, that's sweet. Didn't think of `RankNTypes` in terms of argument and not a constraint. Thanks!

Comment: @SergeyKolbasov A natural transformation has type `forall x. F x -> G x`, so if we want to pass that as an argument, we need `(forall x. F x -> G x) -> SomeResultType`, which is a higher rank type.